# result of &/| operator between two numbers

Tags: python

I was playing around in **python** and I discovered the following

```
>>>777 & 23
1
>>>777 | 23
799
```

I don't understand what putting an &/| operator between two integers does. 
I think this is bitwise operation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types), but I still don't understand bitwise operations

Comment: What isn't clear about "`x | y`  bitwise *or* of *x* and *y*"?

Comment: What is the alternative to bitwise and/or, which is syntactically directly inherited from good old C?

Comment: The search term you are missing is `Truth Table`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Yes, bitwise operations were not clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

777 is first converted to bits as 0000001100001001

```
>>>'{0:016b}'.format(777)
'0000001100001001'
```

Then 23 is converted to bits

```
>>> '{0:016b}'.format(23)
'0000000000010111'
```

Then these two are compared bit by bit (using the & operator), from the left most bit of 777 (0) with left most bit of 23 (0), then 2nd left bit and so forth *i.e.*

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1   (777)
& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &     &
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1    (23)
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Thus, the result of this is:

```
0000000000000001 = 1
```

Same, with the or operator:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1   (777)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1    (23)
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Converting this to int:

```
>>> int('0000001100011111',2)
799
```